# SOCI bind into a rowset pointer when using Core Interface

Tags: c++, oracle, soci

I have following code which I try to use SOCI's core interface and get the result to a rowset object.This code perfectly works but I dont find anyway to get the result set directly to a rowset pointer.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    std::string user = "dbuser1";
    std::string password= "dbuser1";
    std::string alias= "localhost:1521/ora12c"; 
    std::string connection = "service=" + alias + " user=" + user + " password=" + password;
    soci::rowset<soci::row>* rowSet = NULL;
    try
    {
        soci::session sociSession(soci::oracle, connection);
        soci::row row;
        std::vector<std::string> values;
        std::string m_sql = "SELECT *  FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE RECORD_STATUS =:1 AND LOGIN_STATUS=:2";
        values.push_back("0");
        values.push_back("1");

        soci::statement st(sociSession); 
        st.exchange(soci::into(row));
        for(std::size_t i=0; i<values.size(); ++i) 
        {
            st.exchange(soci::use(values[i]));
        }
        st.alloc();
        st.prepare(m_sql);
        st.define_and_bind();
        st.execute(true);

        //TODO get the result set to to rowSet 
    }

    catch (soci::oracle_soci_error const &e)
    {
        cout << "Oracle error: " << e.err_num_
             << " " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (exception const &e)
    {
        cout << "Some other error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The documentation has the section for getting an iterator like below `soci::rowset_iterator<soci::row> it(st, row)` and the closest thing I could find was `exchange_for_rowset` in the statement class. But there was no luck in using that either. Is there any capability to assign the result set directly to  `soci::rowset<soci::row>*` in soci or do I have to iterate over it and assign them. I am new to the Core Interface in soci and didn't find much examples. Highly appreciate the help.

Comment: Unless you are bulk fetching, you have to iterate through the result set. Even in bulk fetching, SOCI does the iteration for you internally.  May I know why do you intend to fetch a chunk of rows at once?